# Getting Middle of string in php

Tags: php, string

I have string like this

```
Ameerpet,|Jeans Corner: 040-50607090@05:45PM/6
```

want to get the substring after `@` and before `/`.
Tried  the following

```
echo substr($str,strpos($str,'@')+1,strpos($str,'/'))
```

But i will get the whole string after `@`

Output `05:45PM/6`

Comment: Nice trick, Its worked:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This,

```
    echo substr($str,
                strpos($str,'@')+1,
                strpos($str,'/') - strpos($str,'@') - 1);
```

The third parameter is not < position > , its < length >

refer this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 2):

You may use `preg_match`

```
$match = preg_match('~@\K[^/]*(?=/)~', $str);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cR7oV7/1)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax of substr is not `substr(str , start ,end)`

The correct syntax is `string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )` 
This is the reason why entire thing is getting printed to achieve the solution you can use the solution provided by @Avinash Raj . However you are trying to get time which is of length 7 then you can use the syntax in this manner

`echo substr($str,strpos($str,'@')+1,7)`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$data = "Ameerpet,|Jeans Corner: 040-50607090@05:45PM/6";    
$first = substr($data, strpos($data, "@") + 1);    
$splitter = "/";
$pieces = explode($splitter, $first );
echo $pieces[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do it with `substr` also

```
$yourString="Ameerpet,|Jeans Corner: 040-50607090@05:45PM/6";
$valueAfterSpecialChar = substr($yourString, strpos($yourString, "@") + 1); 
echo $desiredOutput= substr($valueAfterSpecialChar, 0, strpos($valueAfterSpecialChar, "/"));
```